# webpack compiles but function is not found

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

so I have the following function in a index.js that gets compiled to index.widget.js in the `dist/` directory and loaded via a script tag:

```
import rp from 'request-promise';
import lodash from 'lodash';

const events = (divId, venueId, apiBaseUrl) => {
  rp.uri({
    uri: apiBaseUrl + '/venue/' + venueId,
    json: true
  }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(err){
    throw Error(err);
  });
};
```

**There are 0 console errors**

On the index.html page in which this compiled script is loaded, I try and do:

```
events('events', 1, 'http://example.com');
```

but am told the `events` is not a function in the console when refreshing the page.

The bottom of the compiled file shows:

```
var events = function events(divId, venueId, apiBaseUrl) {
  _requestPromise2.default.uri({
    uri: apiBaseUrl + '/venue/' + venueId,
    json: true
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    throw Error(err);
  });
};
```

If you need to see the full exported and compiled file I can gist it for you.

Am I just a scrub at javascript or did I miss a config in my web pack?

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    event: './events/app.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: '[name].widget.js'
  },
  target: 'web',
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

I am using web pack 2.*

Comment: once webpack compiles, `const events` becomes a local variable, if you want it to use as global, assign it like `window.events = events`